# VirtualBox GPG Erorr NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-22.04

While updating by ubuntu I get the following error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpKzz.png)

GPG error: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF

I've tried using the following command:
`wget -q -O- https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo apt-key add -` 
but this does not work and throws an eror:
`wget -q -O- https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo apt-key add -`

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!